# Google search terms - a landing page with a search in it

Tags: php, html

I have noticed some websites can somehow "sense" what google's search term is.. But I have no idea how this happens. Looking for something in google (i.e. 'french fries') I often end up at pages that quote the search string and say there is no result for it (i.e. 'no result found for french fries'). I was wondering how this happens? I need something similar in my website as all of the information is in different places so google is having trouble putting it all together. The idea is that my website searches for the term that is being searched for in google and provides search results for the terms. How can I implement this and what is this method called (if it has a name) ?

---

Thanks for the answers, I want to further explain what I meant. Google seems to include pages that are generated after the search. How is this possible? The search terms are only sent when a person searches for them and THEN clicks on the link. But in some cases the text "results for  can not be found".. meaning google has indexed the result of the search. How does this happen ?

Comment: Maybe this will help too, as a complete example: http://stevenyork.com/tutorial/how_to_get_search_engine_referal_keywords_using_php . It's not my website, I was just searching answers for the same question.

Comment: apparently nobody knows this but the people that do it.  I've found this question with a really extended answer 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990015/how-some-site-with-fake-links-show-up-in-search-engines-results?lq=1

The main idea is that they add a huge amount of possible urls with queries in their sitemap with as many keywords as possible(taking of Google and search referer, or just dictionaries and wikipedia) so the Google robots can crawl all this url's and they can always have a url ready for any kind of queries the people may write in the search.

It's a lot of work apparently.

Answer (score 1):

> I have noticed some websites can somehow "sense" what google's search term is.. But I have no idea how this happens. Looking for something in google (i.e. 'french fries') I often end up at pages that quote the search string and say there is no result for it (i.e. 'no result found for french fries'). I was wondering how this happens?

Browsers may (and usually do) send a `Referer` (yes, it is misspelt) header that gives the URL of the page that linked to the current page. You can parse the query string of that URL to find out the search term.

> I need something similar in my website as all of the information is in different places so google is having trouble putting it all together.

This suggests you need to better structure the information on your website so that search engines can find the right place. i.e. fixing the problem instead of hacking around it.